# YouTube iframe custom control menu pause function

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, iframe, youtube

I am trying to simply create a menu that can control a YouTube video using the iFrame API.
I have placed a button in the HTML with id="pause_button" and have tried to create a function using jquery to pause the video when clicked.  Here is my HTML doc below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.paresntNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pause_button").click(function(){
        $("#test").append("TEST");
        player.pauseVideo();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>

    <button id="pause_button">STOP</button>
    <div id="test">TEST<br /></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the issue that you are facing? Any error messages? Did you check the JS console?

Comment: The append to the div #test was just to test if the jquery was working properly and it was.

Comment: When I press the button the video does not pause.

Comment: I also get the following errors in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of undefined test.html:14
(anonymous function) test.html:14
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://tunemasher.com/test.html from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'pauseVideo' of undefined test.html:52
(anonymous function) test.html:52
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
h.handle.i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error, that about not being able to call method 'insertBefore' of undefined, is due to a typo in your code; should be:

```
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

(you have paresntNode.)

The second error is due to your origin on the parameter for the URL of the iframe; you left in the example origin (http://example.com), but it should be set to the value of the server that your code is running on. That's a security measure to allow your script to then interact with the player's methods.